# Is the sum of two random variables a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, random-variables

This is a question that I have been struggling with for quite some time, but no luck.

I'm not asking for a final answer, I need to know how to **prove** it.

The question is: Prove whether or not the sum of two random variables is a random variable.

$X_1 + X_2$

Comment: What's your definition of a random variable?

Comment: @littleO  sorry for the ambiguity ... it could be either discrete or continuous, depending on what the person who will explain the proof wants to use

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am a naive. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 : A random variable is a measurable function of an outcome. An outcome is a point in a probability space. An event is a measurable subset of a probability space. These things have precise definitions in the context of the theory of probability.

Comment: I think there's a rather nice proof answering this question here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305989/sum-of-two-random-variables-is-random-variable

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the reply. I am yet to read the measure theoretic approach to probability. Hope to be informed with these concepts soon.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  again, I apologize for the ambiguity. When this question was thrown at us, we were not given any specifics other than X1 and X2 were both random variables. The definition of a random variable that I am going by is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition  any help you could give would be appreciated.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 : Here's a simple example. Suppose you throw two three-sided dice. The possible outcomes are these: $$ \begin{array}{ccc} (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) \\ (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) \\ (3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) \end{array} $$ Now let $X$ be the sum of the two outcomes. $X$ is then a function whose domain is the set of nine elements given above. $X$ is a random variable. $\qquad$

Comment: @Josh : Note that my comment was addressed to someone other than you.

Comment: @Josh : Is you main concern how to prove that $X_1+X_2$ is measurable if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are measurable?

Comment: @MichaelHardy  like I said, we were not given specifics other than X1 and X2 were both random variables. Believe me, people asked, but we were told specifics were not necessary. My main concern is simply to prove that their sum is also a random variable. Someone said "of course the sum is random, because both X1 and X2 are random", but that was just an assertion, not a mathematical proof

Comment: @Josh : Were you given some particular definition of the concept of "random variable"? If so, what was it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy  so, the definition we were given in the group was pretty much identical to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition

Comment: @Josh : In that case, this question probably does qualify as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The way to prove that $X_1+X_2$ is  a random variable is to prove that addition is measurable.

What is *addition* here?  I mean addition in the sense of $+$ in your problem statement.  If you mean addition of integers or of real numbers, the measurability condition is well-known.  If your $X_i$ take values in some complicated infinite dimensional vector space, the measurability condition might need a complicated proof of its own.