# Proof of "Sum of random variables is a random variable"

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

There is already a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305989/how-do-i-show-that-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-is-random-variable) about it where in a proof is given to show that sum of two random variables X and Y, is a random variable. Calling Z=X+Y, the idea is to somehow show that Z is a measurable function.

I am having difficulty understanding the proof.

The proof given in one of the answers is the following.

**Proof:**

There are a number of ways to do it.  A standard trick for proving things like this is by noticing that $\{X+Y\leq z\}^c=\{X + Y > z\} = \displaystyle \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \{X > r\} \cap \{Y > z - r\} $, and that showing that this is in $F$ is enough to show that $X + Y$ is measurable.  Then use the properties of $X$, $Y$, and $\sigma-$algebras to deduce that this set is measurable.

I cannot figure out why $\{X+Y\leq z\}^c=\{X + Y > z\} = \displaystyle \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \{X > r\} \cap \{Y > z - r\} $ is true.
Below is a figure showing the region $Z=X+Y>z$

[image: Fig. 1: Region of X+Y>z]

The claim is that the shaded region is countable union of shaded regions like the one shown below.

[image: Fig. 2: Region common to X>r and Y>z-r]

It is quite easy to show that $$\{X + Y > z\} \supseteq \displaystyle \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \{X > r\} \cap \{Y > z - r\} $$

but I am not clear as to why $$\{X + Y > z\} \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \{X > r\} \cap \{Y > z - r\} $$ is true.

When you take the union of the regions like the one in the second figure above, then between any two such regions, there will always be a gap. When we union over all the rationals, how does that gap get covered completely?

There was a comment about this but I did not quite follow it, especially when I am trying to make sense of it by looking at the above diagrams.

**Comment:**
Obvioulsy whenever $X(\omega)<r$ and $Y(\omega)<z−r$, $(\omega)+(\omega)<$. On the other hand, if $(\omega)+(\omega)=<$, take some rational $$ with $(\omega)<<(\omega)+−$, and you have $(\omega)=−(\omega)<−$.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain as to why $$\{X + Y > z\} \subseteq \displaystyle \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \{X > r\} \cap \{Y > z - r\} $$ is true.

Comment: A much better way would be noticing that if $f$ is continous, then $f^{-1}(\mathrm{X})$ is a Borel set for all Borel sets $\mathrm{X}.$ And then noticing $X + Y = f(X, Y)$ for the function $f(x, y) = x + y,$ which is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\omega$ is in the right union. Then there is $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that  $X(\omega) > r$ and $Y(\omega) >z-r$, then $(X+Y)(\omega) > r+(z-r) = z$ and thus $\omega \in \{X+Y >z\}$.

Conversely, suppose $X(\omega) + Y(\omega) > z$. Choose a rational $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $X(\omega) > r > z - Y(\omega)$ (this is possible because the rational numbers are dense in the real numbers). Then it follows that $\omega \in \{X> r\}\cap\{Y> z-r\}$ and thus $\omega$ is contained in the union.

Comment: I completely messed it up. I will correct my post now. I am sorry but it was exactly the opposite direction that I wanted to understand

Comment: I also included a proof for the other direction. Is everything clear now?

Comment: Thanks for the proof! I just request you to please also give some intuition as to why this works. Rationals are countable but they seem to cover all the reals, which are uncountable. Why is that happening?

Comment: Can you be a little more precise what you mean with "cover all the reals"?

Comment: @EpsiolonDelta. Sorry for the lack of clarity. I am specifically trying to look at it geometrically. In the second figure, I have the region $\{X>z\}\bigcap\{Y>z-r\}$. We are taking union of this over all the rationals $r$. Strictly speaking, we should have taken the union over all the real numbers $r$ but somehow, just the set of rationals is working. Why is that? What is the intuitive reason behind this equality when we are taking the union only over rationals and not over all the reals? Please let me know if I am still not being clear with my question.

Comment: Well, do you think it is strange that $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty ]-n,n[$? It is really the same situation, but a little more complex. Here the index set is $\{1,2,3, \dots\}$ is countable and it still covers $\mathbb{R}$ (on a side note, it is clear that there is no finite subcover, so this example in fact also shows that $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is not compact).

Comment: @QuantumSpace, please can you reference a book for beginners like me to understand this?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales This depends on your background and goals.

Comment: @QuantumSpace. I'm an engineer, I like maths; I taking master's courses in statistics. I looking forward to understand all symbols.