# Sum, product and scalar multiples of random variables are random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am taking a course on Advanced Probability Theory. The definition of a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, S, P)$ is as follows:

> $X\colon \Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable iff for every $\alpha\in \mathbb R$, we have that $(X\le \alpha) :=\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)\le \alpha\}\in S$.

The professor then commented that for any random variables $X$, $Y$ on $(\Omega, S, P)$ and any real $c$, we have that $X + Y$, $cX$, and $XY$ (all defined pointwise on $\Omega$) are random variables. It was said that the proof of this requires a "lot of analysis", and was thus deferred.

However, I couldn't find a proof of these facts anywhere.

Any help or a reference to a resource?

Comment: Proving those facts are usually left as exercises in many courses and can be found on this site, for example [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305989/how-do-i-show-that-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-is-random-variable).

Comment: A measurable function of a measurable function is...a measurable function.

Answer (score 0):

These facts are proven in almost every measure theory or probability theory book. The result doesn't really require any hard analysis; the result is  almost immediate from the continuity of addition and multiplication, modulo the proof that $(f, g)$ is measurable if and only if $f$ and $g$ are both measurable. You can see these facts proved using this strategy in theorem 1.91 on page 40 of "Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course" by Klenke.