# What does it mean to be the variance of a single value?

Tags: random-variables, variance

I've seen several sources of the Weak Law of Large Numbers (WLLN) proof and they all have something along the lines of the following:

Using Chebyshev's inequality $ P(|X-\mu|\geq a) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$, we have,

$$ P(|\overline{X}-\mu|\geq a) \leq \frac{Var(\overline{X})}{a^2} $$

**Reflection:** 
There appears to be some very loose substitution of $X$ with $\overline{X}$, with no justification and this is bothering me. My understanding of variance is that it's a function of $X$, which itself is a function, specifically that the variance is the average squared distance from the population mean $\mu$ across ALL $X_i$ in the range (set) of $X$. Whereas $\overline{X}$ is just a single value. Furthermore, in the algebraic proof that $Var(\overline{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ (which is also used as part of the overall WLLN proof), there is a step that simplifies $Var(X_i)$ to $\sigma^2$, so once again variance is being applied to a single value.

What's more disturbing is that results from Googling "variance of a single value" suggest that it is 0.

What's *even* more disturbing is that authors simply use variance this way (with the only previous definition of it being on a set of values), and no one questions it.

Last I checked, a set and a single value are different constructs.

Hence...

**Question:** 
What does it mean to be the variance of a single value?

**Notes based on answers:**

1. There appears to be some confusion between $X$ and $X_i$. My understanding is X is the probability function of the probability space $<\Omega, U, P>$, and operates on individual elements $\omega$ of the sample
   space $\Omega$. Whereas $X_i$ is a single observation of $X$, i.e.,
   when I read $X_i$, I am actually reading $X(\omega_i)$, where
   $\omega_i$ is the $i$th element of the sample space. In the case
   where $\Omega$ is heights of people, $\omega_i$ might be John's
   height ($\omega_{i+1}$ might be Jack's height). X(John's height) =
   173.2cm, X(Jack's height) = 181.5cm. So variance of $X$ makes sense, while variance of a single observation of $X$ does not. Now if $X_i$
   is in fact not what I understand it to be, then a more formal
   definition of $X_i$ would go a long way.

Comment: The *population* variance of a 1-element set is always 0.  The *sample* variance of a 1-element set is undefined.

Comment: $\overline X$ is a random variable in just the same way as $X + Y$ is a random variable whenever $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. A capital letter (especially $X, Y, Z$) almost always means a random variable in this context!

Comment: If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are random variables then $\bar X = (X_1 + \cdots + X_n)/n$ is also a random variable.

Comment: The issue is lack of formality with definitions. Please see my comments to answers - it would be more productive to continue the conversation there.

Comment: @Ash See if [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96000) helps with basic intuitions. Your $X_1,X_2$ (assuming a sample of size 2) correspond with $X,Y$ in this post.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio There are several further questions that arise by bringing in another question into the picture so rather than go down that path, it would be lot easier to clarify my point #1 under 'Notes based on answers', specifically, the formal definition of $X_i$ (given my definition of the probability space and $X$).

Comment: I think everyone here has already done an admirable job in responding, but I'll address one thing.  $X_i$ is _not_ an observation of $X$; it might better be thought of as an _instantiation_ of $X$.  They're the same function, just with different names.  An observation of $X$ -- that is something we've observed, something that happened; the _outcome_ of our random experiment -- is generally written $x$.

Comment: Jack's height is not an $ \omega_i $. If we assume Jack comes from some population where we know how heights are distributed -- and say this distribution has pdf $f_X(x)$ -- then, his height is $X_i$, with $X_i \sim f_X(x)$. (Or rather, $X_i$ _will turn out to be_ Jack's [or John's or whoever's] height, since we don't know whose height we're measuring until we've measured it -- random experiment and all.)  Before we've measured it, it ($X_i$) comes from a distribution that has, for example, variance. After we've measured (observed) it, it ($x_i$) is a number. Numbers don't have variance.

Comment: @dmk Thanks. Your explanation seems to make the most sense to me. So can I think of an instantiation as a function where the input ($\omega$) is unknown, and can therefore represent ANY outcome in the sample space? So $X_i : \Omega -> \mathbb{R}$ accounts for ALL possible $\omega$? It's the before/after stuff that is likely causing my confusion.

Comment: @Ash I mentioned this in my comments below already, namely $X_i:\Omega\to\mathbb{R},\bar{X}:\Omega \to\mathbb{R}$. Note $X_1,X_2,X_3,$ etc. are random variables (i.e. functions) defined on the same probability space. How else would you add them if they don't share the same space?  You kept bringing up "$X,$" which doesn't appear anywhere in the statement of the law of large numbers, which is the whole context of your question.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio $X$ appears in the proof when referencing Chebyshev. And $X$ is my understanding of the random variable on a probability space. It doesn't matter whether the theorem references $X$ or $X_i$ because in either case, I don't understand the distinction between the two well enough to make sense of the theorem. I asked for clarification multiple times. I requested a formal definition of $X_i$. I updated my question to reflect my confusion. In here I noted all my understandings so far. dmk just happens to be the only one so far who has addressed these - and in a way that makes sense.

Comment: @Ash If you understand the definition of a random variable, then you are good. $X_i$ is just a random variable. It is not an observation of another random variable $X$ as you mention in your post. Chebyshev can be applied to any random variable satisfying its hypothesis, whether you want to label the RV as $X$, $X_1$, $Z$ or any name you want to give it.

Comment: @Ash It seems you have a notational problem. We use $X_1,X_2,X_3...$ etc because we are simply indexing a sequence of random variables.  The notation $X_i$ does NOT mean it depends upon some other random variable $X$ for its existence.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion stems from thinking about what WLLN means "in the real world" - it does tell you something about how "samples from a distribution" behave. But in the measure-theoretic formalism, the "values of the samples" are just independent random variables. If I tell you that I rolled a fair die $1000$ times, then you can think of the values of the rolls as IID random variables, and you can therefore also think of the average as a random variable (and calculate probabilities involving them). Theorems like WLLN and CLT and so on are then applicable to these "samples".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that the kind of mean and variance that you use in the question are definitions used in descriptive statistics, not probability,
whereas the mean and variance referred to in the weak law of large numbers are a different thing entirely.

The longer answer:

The weak law of large numbers (WLLN) is a theorem in the theory of probability.
In the theory of probability, a real-valued random variable
(such as one of the $X_i$ in a sequence of i.i.d. variables)
is a function from an underlying probability space to the real numbers.
We might say in one example that $X_i$ has the value $0$ with probability $\frac23$
and $1$ with probability $\frac13,$ or we might say that $X_i$ has a standard normal distribution.

A random variable defined in this way has (usually) an expected value and (usually) a variance.
When the variance exists, it is typically not zero unless the probability distribution is trivial, such as $X_i = 2$ with probability $1,$ in which case the variance is zero.

In summary, in a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$
to which the weak law of large numbers might apply,
each variable has a mean and variance that are determined by the probability distribution of that random variable without knowing what particular value that variable will take by chance and without any regard to the values that any other variables in the sequence might take by chance.

This will make no sense at all if you try to interpret it by taking a list of numbers such as $3,14,2,4,9,1$ and considering the mean and variance of those numbers.
The number $3$ is not a random variable (at least, not a non-trivial one).
The mean and variance of that list of numbers are descriptive statistics,
numbers that describe properties of the list, not of the individual elements of the list.

We use the terms *mean* and *variance* for both random variables and descriptive statistics because they have similar formulas and analogous properties.
It's an unfortunate side effect that people sometimes use the definition from one context in another context where it does not apply.

It doesn't help that explanations of the law of large numbers (weak or otherwise) tend to incorporate other language of descriptive statistics, such as "sample" or "outcomes of a series of experiments."
A motivation for using those terms is that this theorem of probability will be used to justify some methods of descriptive statistics, and they give hints about how it will be used, but the theorem itself is still fundamentally probabilistic, not descriptive.

---

As mentioned in comments and illustrated in the updated question, a more concrete description of a suitable sample space for the WLLN may help.

First of all, while most texts don't specify this explicitly, if you look at typical examples of sample spaces you may notice that the outcomes in the sample space are mutually exclusive. For example, a typical sample space for two tosses of a coin is $\{ HH, HT, TH, TT \},$ a set of four outcomes, exactly one of which will occur. If the two tosses come up $HT$ in that order, they cannot also have come up $TH$ or $HH.$

If all you are ever going to do in a particular probability exercise is to choose one person living in a certain region at a certain time and measure that one person's height, you could use a list of the heights of people living in that region at that time as a sample space. But if you're going to do more than that, you will need a bigger sample space; when you use the list of heights of people as your sample space, you can't talk about probability that you will have measured both John's height and Jack's height, because those acts of measurement are mutually exclusive.

One useful sample space for the weak law of large numbers would be the set $\Omega$ of all infinite sequences of real numbers.
The aim here is (roughly speaking) that if
$\omega = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) \in \Omega,$
we could interpret $a_1$ as the height of the first person selected from a population, $a_2$ as the height of the second person, and so forth.

You might see a problem right away with using such a sample space for the height measurements of a sample of people from the people living in a certain region at a certain time: you have only finitely many people to assign to positions in an infinite sequence. The problem arises because if you restrict yourself to selecting samples of people from a fixed finite set of people without replacement, you can't say anything about what happens with $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ in the limit as $n\to\infty$, because to define the limit you need to consider cases where $n$ is greater than the number of people in your finite set.
Another hitch is that when you select your sample without replacement, $X_2$ is not independent of $X_1.$
One way to resolve these problems is to select your sample not from a finite set of actual living people, but to select from an infinite set of all people who could possibly have lived in any possible history of the world. A simpler way to resolve it is to allow the sample to be taken with replacement so that if John's height is measured first, John still has just as much chance to be selected for the second measurement as he originally had to be selected for the first measurement, and John (or anyone else) can be measured as many times as it takes to fill out a list of $n$ measurements.

To define a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ of events and a probability function $\mathbb P$ over this sample space $\Omega,$ I will adapt a sample space described in the first few pages of [a set of notes by Greg Lawler at the University of Chicago](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/probnotes.pdf).

For each positive integer $n$, we define $\Omega_n$ as the set of finite sequences of real numbers of length $n.$ We define $\mathcal F_n$ as a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_n$ and we define $\mathbb P_n$ as a probability measure on $\mathcal F_n.$
(The exact forms of $\mathcal F_n$ and $\mathbb P_n$ will have to support whatever distribution we want $X_i$ to have in our particular application of the WLLN; in Lawler's notes $X_i$ is a Bernoulli variable with $p=\frac12.$)

Now we can define an event $A \subseteq \Omega$ in terms of a set $E$ of finite sequences as follows:

$$ A = \{(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\mid (a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in E\subseteq \Omega_n\}. $$

Define $\mathbb P^0(A) = \mathbb P_n(E).$
This defines a function $\mathbb P^0$ on a set algebra
$$ \mathcal F^0 = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal F_n. $$
Sadly, $\mathcal F^0$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra, so we have to invoke some advanced mathematics to extend $\mathcal F^0$ to a $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathcal F$ and to extend $\mathbb P^0$ to a probability function $\mathbb P$ on $\mathcal F.$

Now we can apply the WLLN to the probability space
$(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P).$
Let $\omega = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) \in \Omega.$
Then $X_1(\omega) = a_1,$ $X_2(\omega) = a_2,$ and in general
$X_i(\omega) = a_i.$
If $X = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$ then
$X(\omega)$ is the arithmetic mean of the first $n$ numbers in $\omega.$

This defines each $X_i$ as a random variable and also defines $X$ as a random variable.
In order to actually use the WLLN, we will have had to define $\mathbb P$ in such a way that the probability distribution of each $X_i$ is the same as the probability distribution of any $X_j$ and so that any particular $X_i$ is independent of all $X_j$ for $j\neq i.$

As you may have noticed, it takes a lot more ink and effort to explicitly describe a suitable sample space for an application of the WLLN than to make the usual statement of the theorem.
(Really a *lot* of ink and effort, because I have glossed over significant parts of the description, so the description could be much, much longer if these details were fully described.) It is much simpler to describe the properties of all the necessary random variables you will need for an such an exercise (including random variables that are defined in terms of other random variables), including their joint distributions, with the understanding that a suitable sample space for these variables exists, so that's how things are normally done.

Comment: Thank you for the insight into descriptive stats Vs probability theory and the confusion that arises when there's crossover. I agree. The individual $X_i$s that you have mentioned are individual *observations* of the random variable $X$, correct? If not, some elaboration to clarify here might help. Assuming my understanding is right, $X$ is defined to be a function from a sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so it MUST take as input some $\omega$ and output some $r$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Variance is defined for such an $X$, not for an individual $X_i$?

Comment: Each individual $X_i$ is a random variable by itself. If $X$ is mentioned in a proof separately from $X_i,$ it must also be defined. The usual definition seems to be, for a given list of $n$ random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, $X = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$ The inequality you cited should be written only once, not twice, however; there's no reason to define $\bar X$ as something different from $X,$ although I do notice some sources (perhaps associated with data science) are sloppy about this.

Comment: In short, you're not fundamentally wrong to think that there is something wrong about the alternating use of $X$ and $\bar X,$ because there is.

Comment: Hm, the way you have now defined $X$ is the same as that of $\overline{X}$ (in descriptive terms, the average). To me, a random variable (which is actually a function) MUST be defined to operate on $\omega$ in some sample space $\Omega$. That's the formal definition of a random variable. $\Omega$ can be the heights of people for example. So we now end up at the same point as my comment in the other answer: given the definition of $\overline{X}$, in order for it to be a random variable (function), what would its sample space be? Associating back to heights of people, what would this look like?

Comment: What I think is fundamentally wrong is the looseness (if I could pick one keyword in my question, it'd be this) with which things are interchanged and I attribute this to the looseness with which things are defined. If everything (including notation) is formally defined (or proved if it's actually a consequence of a formal definition), there'd be no confusion.

Comment: You have too constrictive a definition of a random variable. A random variable is **any** measurable function of the sample space. The mean height of $100$ randomly selected people, for example, is a random variable. So is the height of the first person you selected.

Comment: A sample space might be lists of numbers representing heights of people who have been randomly selected in sequence. That's a very large sample space.

Comment: "any measurable function of the sample space". Sure, but "of the sample space" implies a single element of the space. A mean operates on a set of elements, not a single element. So to me, the sample space for a function that calculates the mean aren't single elements (heights of people), but sets of elements (randomly selected subsets of heights of people).

Comment: You may call it constrictive but I call it formal, and the lack of it is why I'm here confused to begin with. If this were a computer program, I'd get a runtime error when passing in $\overline{X}$ to a function that expects a random variable... unless of course I also *formally* define the sample space and the random variable function for $\overline{X}$, before passing it in.

Comment: @Ash I answered this question in my comment

Comment: Added a section to my question called 'Notes based on answers' that might shed bit more light on my confusion.

Comment: I just saw the newest edit to this answer. Really appreciate the extra ink and effort and since everything now makes sense to me, I'm happy to accept. It might be hard to imagine, but this was the key bit: Let $\omega = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) \in \Omega.$
Then $X_1(\omega) = a_1,$ $X_2(\omega) = a_2,$ and in general
$X_i(\omega) = a_i.$
If $X = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$ then
$X(\omega)$ is the arithmetic mean of the first $n$ numbers in $\omega.$

Comment: Defining $\omega$ in such a way helped me see: 1) $X$ is a random variable, as you have defined it in a way that is consistent with my understanding of how a random variable is defined, specifically a function that operates on elements from the sample space, and 2) $X$ is also a mean the way you have defined it since the elements it operates on ($\omega$) are actually sets (or sequences) of elements, not single elements, and this was the key difference from the definition given by Golden_Ratio. Combining (1) and (2), we get what I was looking for: how a mean can also be a random variable.

Comment: Finally, thanks to various people chipping in, I was able to see that $Var(\overline{X})$ does not read "variance of a numeric value", rather "variance of the mean of $X$ (whose value is not yet known)". The next hurdle to overcome in my head was accepting that "the mean of $X$" is also a random variable (following the strict definition of one) and once that was cleared up (as per my last 2 comments), everything made sense.

Answer (score 4):

Just as $X_i$ is a random variable, the sample average $\bar X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is also a random variable. The variance of a random variable is some nonnegative constant. If the random variable itself is (almost surely) a constant, then its variance is zero.

Comment: Thanks. There's some loose notation going on here as well, if you could please elaborate. $Var(X)$ is defined for the random variable $X$. $X_i$ is not the random variable $X$ (the way I read it) but the $i$th outcome of the random variable $X$, which again is a single value.

Comment: @Ash When we say $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid, it means all $X_i$s are random variables having an identical population distribution and are independent.  The $X_i$s represent different observations from a population, not outcomes of a single random variable.  In a practical sense, let's say $X_i$ represents the height of individual $i$ in your sample.  Note this value is treated as random *before* observation; of course, after observation, it is a known constant.

Comment: Yes. When I said "outcome", I was in fact thinking of observation, so we're on the same page there. $X$ is defined to be a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so it MUST take as input $\omega$ and output some $r$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Defining $\overline{X}$ the way you have and claiming it's a random variable (I'm sure it is but it...) doesn't make sense because it's not at all apparent that $\overline{X}$ follows the same requirements as $X$. In particular, what would be the sample space for $\overline{X}$?

Comment: @Ash Why does it not make sense?  Consider $X_i:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and define $\bar X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \bar X(\omega):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega).$

Comment: @Ash [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305989/how-do-i-show-that-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-is-random-variable) may also help

Comment: Can you clarify how you've defined $X_i$ this way? My understanding is that's the definition of $X$, and not $X_i$, which is a single observation of $X$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144774/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-ash).